# Nodejs: UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported content encoding "zlib"

Tags: node.js, zlib

when i upload .gzip file, it give me this error in nodejs console log. 
Error:

```
UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported content encoding "zlib"
```

My Api for file upload:

```
http://192.168.0.105:4000/api/mqtt_collector/uploadFile
```

API Code:

```
var upload = multer({
storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './Media/Client_Invoice',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
   });
});
module.exports.uploadFile = upload.single('NETWORK_FILE'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Uploade Successful');
}
```

We are develop router remote system using mqtt plugin. When router send file on this api. I get this error.

It is working well in postman, but when router send this file, it gives error.

Comment: The error tells what's wrong. There's no content-type 'zlib' supported by your platform

Comment: I am using window platform. Is this reason for this error?

Comment: We cannot help you if you won't specify fully the problem you have. Give the client code, server code, tell us the way you upload the file